# javafx alternative Impl_getURL();

Tags: javafx

Hello i ran across a problem in my code. i used a line

```
view.getSpeler1Kaarten()[i].getImage().impl_getUrl().contains("WippenGame/View/Images/BlancoKaart.png")
```

but its giving me warnings when i start my program.
Also i looked up why impl_getUrl() had a stripe trough it and it said it is sometimes dangerous to use it and that most of the time there is a better alternative for it. Has anyone an idea what the alternative could be? i basicly have to see if imagview contains a certain image.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't use the URL to compare the images like that.

You presumably load that particular image somewhere in your code:

```
Image blancoKaart = new Image(...);
```

and it is (almost always) good practice to ensure you only load it once.

So now you can just do

```
view.getSpeler1Kaarten()[i].getImage() == blancoKaart ;
```